# asp.net mvc view css not showing as expected

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.Net MVC and was wondering why and how I can resolve an issue with a text box not taking the CSS as I had expected.

My CSS is

```
.newsLetter {
border-radius:4px; 
background-color:#393939; 
width:100%; 
border: 1px solid #393939;
```

}

The pre MVC \ View HTML is

```
<h2>NEWSLETTER</h2>
  <p style="color:#b5b5b5; float:left;">Sign up to our News Lettter</p>
  <p><input type="text" name="" value="Your Name" class="newsLetter mainText" /></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="" value="Your Email Address"class="newsLetter mainText" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="" value="Subscribe" class="smallBlueButton" />
```

The View I am using to render this

```
<div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "newsletter mainText"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
```

This is the actual result in the HTML

```
<div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="newsletter mainText text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Name must be a string with a maximum length of 50." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
```

What I would like help with is how do I get it to drop the text-box single-line CSS.

Any and all help very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS uses a class of .newsLetter (upper case L) but the class you're rendering in your HTML is 'newsletter' (lower case L).  They need to match.

Comment: but why is it bring in the text-box class too?

Comment: I hadnt noticed the casing issue... so thank you for that

Comment: The 'text-box' class comes from ASP.NET MVC's EditorFor.  Not entirely sure of the ins and outs, but I believe it's to do with the unobtrusive validation.